# React Native android TextInput disappears under keyboard when changing to emoticons

Tags: android, react-native, expo

We wrapped our `TextInput` inside the `KeyboardAvoidingView` and all works fine until one changes the keyboard to choose an emoticon. The size of the keyboard changes then and covers the `TextInput`.

It is possible then to write an emoticon but the user can't see anymore what is going on with his/her text.

Here's our code:

```
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

...

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={headerHeight}
      style={styles.screen}
    >
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        <View style={styles.radContainer}>
          <TextInput
              style={styles.addCommentInput}
              value={comment}
              onChangeText={changeCommentHandler}
              onSubmitEditing={() => {
                sendCommentHandler();
              }}
           />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

...

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    alignContent: "space-between",
    backgroundColor: styleConstants.colors.silver03,
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  radContainer: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  addCommentInput: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderColor: styleConstants.colors.silver01,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    fontFamily: "work-sans_regular",
    fontSize: 14,
    height: 40,
    paddingBottom: 8,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 8,
    textAlignVertical: "center",
  },
});
```

[image: Nokia Android test]

We're using react native with expo SDK44. The GIF you see is from a test flight binary on a Nokia Android version 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is related with React Native, here's the PR in [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/34749), it is merged but not active in current version of React Native 0.70.6, you can add the fixed code manually and maintain validity until it is added to RN, using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)